# What is the spin of a magnetic impurity?

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics

I am reading this seemingly important paper [Local Magnetic Moment Associated with an Iron Atom Dissolved in Various Transition Metal Alloys](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.125.541). It is strange to me that the magnetic impurity has non-integral value (such as 5.2) of magnetic moment.

Should not the total spin of any system be an integer or a half-integer? This should be independent of the interaction?

Answer (score 0):

in my view, magnetic impurities are seperated in system and the content of impurities, for example is 2%. In this way, the overral spin cannot be an ideal integer or half-integer.